# CSS class/id style not being applied to <nav>, <footer> and <header> descendants included using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a dynamic website using PHP, but I have encountered a problem - all descendants of `<nav>`, `<footer>` and `<header>` are ignoring their class CSS formatting, but not class-specific CSS is taking effect on them. For example:

This formatting is not affecting elements inside `<footer>`:

```css
footer section #main-footer-section
{
 background-color: #444554;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <section id="main-footer-section">

 </section>
 <section id="bottom-footer-section">
  <p id="copyright-mark"><?php echo date("Y") ?>&copy;</p>
 </section>
</footer>
```

But this is affecting the `<footer>` contents:

```css
footer section
{
 background-color: #444554;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <section id="main-footer-section">

 </section>
 <section id="bottom-footer-section">
  <p id="copyright-mark"><?php echo date("Y") ?>&copy;</p>
 </section>
</footer>
```

Could anyone please advise if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id is attached to the footer so it's

```css
footer section#main-footer-section
{
 background-color: #444554;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Your code snippet is looking for Footer > Section > element with #main-footer-section instead of Footer > Section with #main-footer-section

Answer (score 0):

Using it like that:
`footer section #main-footer-section`
would require a structure like

```
<footer>
  <section>
    <div id="main-footer-section">
  </section>
</footer>
```

Every whitespace in CSS definitions stands for another level down.

Your structure would be matched by this:

```
footer section#main-footer-section { /* ... */ }
```